# Carousel animation for left button works incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on my own carousel script, but the transition animation for the left button is not working correctly.

I think the problem is in the `test` function under `if($move=="left")`, but I am unable to figure out what is causing this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  /*********** CAROUSEL **********/
  var carouselInterval = setInterval(function() {
    moveCarousel();
  }, 3000);

  var carouselImageCount = $("#carousel li").length; // count the number of images
  var transitionCount = 0;

  function moveCarousel() {
    transitionCount++;
    if (transitionCount == carouselImageCount) {
      transitionCount = 0;
      $(this).css({
        marginLeft: 0
      });
    }
    $("#carousel ul").animate({
      marginLeft: "-100%"
    }, 1000, function() {
      $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
      $(this).css({
        marginLeft: 0
      });
    });
  }

  // when the cursur hovers on the image

  $("#carousel,.carouselArrowRight,.carouselArrowLeft").hover(function() {
    clearInterval(carouselInterval);
  }, function() {
    carouselInterval = setInterval(function() {
      moveCarousel();
    }, 3000);
  });

  /*********** CAROUSEL **********/

  /*********** CAROUSEL ARROWS ************/
  $(".carouselArrowRight").click(function() {
    //moveCarousel();
    test("right");
  });
  $(".carouselArrowLeft").click(function() {
    test("left");
    //moveCarousel();
  });

  function test($move) {
      if ($move == "left") {
        transitionCount--;
        $(this).css({
          "margin-left": "100%"
        });
        $("#carousel ul").animate({
          marginLeft: "100%"
        }, 1000, function() {
          $(this).find("li:first").before($(this).find("li:last"));
          $(this).css({
            marginLeft: 0
          });
        });
      } else {
        transitionCount++;
        if (transitionCount == carouselImageCount) {
          transitionCount = 0;
          $(this).css({
            marginLeft: 0
          });
        }
        $("#carousel ul").animate({
          marginLeft: "-100%"
        }, 1000, function() {
          $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
          $(this).css({
            marginLeft: 0
          });
        });
      }
    }
    /*********** CAROUSEL ARROWS ************/
});
```

```css
#carousel {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#carousel ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 330px;
  display: flex;
}
#carousel ul li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="sectionArea01">
  <div class="wrapCarousel">
    <div class="carouselAlignment">
      <p class="carouselArrowLeft">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt="">
      </p>

      <div class="wrapInner">
        <div id="carousel">
          <ul id="carouselImages">
            <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/600x330" alt="">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/600x330" alt="">
            </li>
            <li>
              <img src="http://placehold.it/600x330" alt="">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p class="carouselArrowRight">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt="">
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLJXNe)

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle or any working online editor... thanks :)

Comment: I've changed the wording of your question to be better readable, and I changed your code so it is now in a runnable snippet. I have left a `<!-- .. -->` comment in the question with information that was not included in the question, but is helpful for anyone that tries to answer the question. Please click the edit link under your question and provide this information where the comment is now.

Comment: im sorry for my code snippet because its very ugly. notice that when left button was clicked, the animation is not like the same as the right button was clicked

Comment: so that's the problem of your code ? LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change items before animation. Also fixed margins in animations to absolute values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  /*********** CAROUSEL **********/
  var carouselInterval = setInterval(function() {
    moveCarousel();
  }, 3000);

  var carouselImageCount = $("#carousel li").length; // count the number of images
  var transitionCount = 0;

  function moveCarousel() {
    transitionCount++;
    if (transitionCount == carouselImageCount) {
      transitionCount = 0;
      $(this).css({
        marginLeft: 0
      });
    }
    $("#carousel ul").animate({
      marginLeft: "-600px"
    }, 2500, function() {
      $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
      $(this).css({
        marginLeft: 0
      });
    });
  }

  // when the cursur hovers on the image

  $("#carousel,.carouselArrowRight,.carouselArrowLeft").hover(function() {
    clearInterval(carouselInterval);
  }, function() {
    carouselInterval = setInterval(function() {
      moveCarousel();
    }, 5000);
  });

  /*********** CAROUSEL **********/

  /*********** CAROUSEL ARROWS ************/
  $(".carouselArrowRight").click(function() {
    //moveCarousel();
    test("right");
  });
  $(".carouselArrowLeft").click(function() {
    test("left");
    //moveCarousel();
  });

  function test($move) {
      if ($move == "left") {
        transitionCount--;
        $("#carousel ul").find("li:first").before($("#carousel ul").find("li:last"));

        $("#carousel ul").css({marginLeft: "-600px"})
          .animate({marginLeft: "0"}, 2500);
      } else {
        transitionCount++;
        if (transitionCount == carouselImageCount) {
          transitionCount = 0;
          $(this).css({
            marginLeft: 0
          });
        }
        $("#carousel ul").animate({
          marginLeft: "-600px"
        }, 2500, function() {
          $(this).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
          $(this).css({
            marginLeft: 0
          });
        });
      }
    }
    /*********** CAROUSEL ARROWS ************/
});
```

```css
#carousel {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#carousel ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 330px;
  display: flex;
}
#carousel ul li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="sectionArea01">
  <div class="wrapCarousel">
    <div class="carouselAlignment">
      <p class="carouselArrowLeft">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt="">
      </p>

      <div class="wrapInner">
        <div id="carousel">
          <ul id="carouselImages">
            <li id="black">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/600x330/000000/eeeeee" alt="">
            </li>
            <li id="red">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/600x330/ff0000/eeeeee" alt="">
            </li>
            <li id="green">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/600x330/00ff00/dddddd" alt="">
            </li>
            <li id="blue">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/600x330/0000ff/aaaaaa" alt="">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <p class="carouselArrowRight">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt="">
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```